# Run same Databricks notebook for different arguments concurrently?

Tags: pyspark, databricks

The following code (not mine) is able to run NotebookA and NotebookB concurrently. I need some help to figure out how to pass multiple arguments to the same notebooks.

I want to pass this list of arguments to each notebook:

```
args = {}
args["arg1"] = "some value"
args["arg2"] = "another value"
```

If I wanted to pass the arguments above to each of the running notebooks, what will I need to amend in the code below?

Here is the working code:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
pool = ThreadPool(10)
inputs = [("NotebookA", "NotebookB") ]

run_in_parallel = lambda x: dbutils.notebook.run(x, 1800) 

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, wait 
pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(3) 
results = [] 
with ThreadPoolExecutor(3) as pool:
  for x in inputs: 
    results.extend(pool.map(run_in_parallel, list(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `dbutils.notebook.run` accepts the 3rd argument as well, this is a map of parameters (see [documentation for more details](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html#api)). So in your case, you'll need to change definition of the `run_in_parallel` to something like this:

```py
run_in_parallel = lambda x: dbutils.notebook.run(x, 1800, args)
```

and the rest of the code should be the same.

If you'll want to pass different arguments to different notebooks, then you'll need to have a list of tuples, and pass this list to a `map`, like this:

```py
data = [('notebook 1', {'arg1':'abc'}), ('notebook2', {'arg1': 'def', 'arg2': 'jkl'})]
...
run_in_parallel = lambda x: dbutils.notebook.run(x[0], 1800, x[1]) 
with ThreadPoolExecutor(3) as pool:
  results.extend(pool.map(run_in_parallel, data))
```